# Partner Community Roles

Tags: community, roles

I have a partner community where I set my default # of Partner Roles to 1. I do have super user access granted. However for some of the Parter User I create I only see one role option on their user record and for others I see three role options on their user record. Why is there an inconsistency. When do three roles show up instead of one?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the PartnerRole options are set when a user is created. This means that for existing users, you can't restrict them to just one role - they'll always have a choice of three.

As far as I know, the only way around this is to recreate these user accounts.

Comment: What are the main differences between User, Manager User and Executive User? I don't know what to select since previously it always defaulted for me.

Comment: The only real effect they have is on record visibility - if you make someone a Manager User for example, they will be able to see all the records of all persons with the User role. Executive Users can see the records of all Manager Users and Users.

Comment: Sorry one more question. I just realized I said it was Partner Roles, it is actually Customer Community Plus User Roles, so in this scenario what kind of impact would it have since users don't own records they are just contacts associated to an Account they should see?

Comment: No, it's the same - the Customer Community Plus accounts work the same way the Partner Community accounts in this instance.